# initdb: cannot be run as root

Tags: linux, centos, postgresql

I want to create a database cluster in PostgSQL on CentOS.

When I type the command 'initdb', the result goes like the following:

```
[root@cll agensgraph]# initdb

initdb: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will own the server process.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[root@cll ~]# sudo chown jessica:jessica /usr/local/agdata/
[root@cll ~]# cd /usr/local/
[root@cll local]# ll

total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  2 jessica jessica    6 Feb 26 18:06 agdata
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root    root      56 Feb 26 03:31 agensgraph
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root    4096 Feb 24 21:01 bin
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root       6 Nov  5  2016 etc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root       6 Nov  5  2016 games
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root    root     160 Feb 24 21:01 include
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root    root    4096 Feb 24 21:01 lib
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root       6 Nov  5  2016 lib64
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root       6 Nov  5  2016 libexec
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root       6 Nov  5  2016 sbin
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root    root     169 Feb 24 21:01 share
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root       6 Nov  5  2016 src

[root@cll local]# cd agdata/
[root@cll agdata]# initdb
initdb: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.

[root@cll agdata]# su -l jessica
Last login: Mon Feb 26 23:31:29 CST 2018 from 192.168.109.1 on pts/2
[jessica@cll ~]$ cd /usr/local/agensgraph/
[jessica@cll agensgraph]$ initdb
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "jessica".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
Data page checksums are disabled.
fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/agdata ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    ag_ctl -D /usr/local/agdata -l logfile start

[jessica@cll agensgraph]$
```

### Explanation

[enter link description here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/9.1%E5%8F%82%E8%80%833)

Comment: The (possible) reason this was downvoted may be that the PostgreSQL database usually is run as the `postgres` or `postgresql` (or similar) user, not as an actual human user. Having the database run as a system user instead of as yourself ensures that it's only the system user that may access the database file store (it's a safety feature).  It is _highly_ unusual to run any database engine as a human user. The `postgresql-setup` script takes care of the setup for you and knows what the correct PostgreSQL user is on your system.

Answer (score 3):

The PostgreSQL database requires that the initialization is carried out as the user who will actually run the database process. This user is not *you* but a system user account like `postgres` or `postgresql` or similar.

On CentOS, following [the instructions found in the PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation#Initialize), you would, as root, do either

```
service postgresql-9.6 initdb
```

or

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
```

(assuming it's PostgreSQL 9.6 you're setting up).

[Another site suggests](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-7)

```
sudo postgresql-setup initdb
```

If the PostgreSQL package on your machine came with documentation (it's bound to have done), then this documentation would explain exactly how the version of the database should be initialized.

Comment: What is this `postgresql-setup` executable? I'm on version 9.2, and I don't seem to have it

Comment: @JamesWierzba What Unix?

Comment: "Amazon Linux version 2017.03" -- special amazon fork of linux, used in various AWS services. They have their own rpm repo with their own packages, seems like amazon customizes everything, including package contents itself